# web.config rewrite rule not working after adding similar match URL expression

Tags: web-config

i am trying to implement following URL rewrite rule in my web.config. The rule i have mentioned below is working fine, the problem is when i add one more valid expression let say `|news/Announces-Magento-Partnership` to it, site stops working and it give 500 internal server error, i tried making another rule but it is still not working.

```
 <match url="^es/(news/Announces-Autodesk-Forge-Partnership|news/completes-sas-70-certification|news/becomes-oracle-gold-level-partner|news/continues-global-expansion|news/breaks-ground-on-new-headquarters|news/onboards-nine-new-team-members|news/best-places-to-work-2018-honoree|news/101-best-and-brightest-2017|news/2018-healthiest-employers|news/techgateway-day-2017-broward-county|news/best-custom-business-software-developer-2017|news/2018-best-bespoke-software-development-firm|news/reviewed-fastest-growing-tech-2017|news/raises-funds-for-victims-of-harvey|news/makes-incs-honor-roll-sixth-time|news/to-exhibit-at-the-2017-nsc-congress-and-expo|news/joins-ellie-mae-pro-consulting-partner-program|news/announces-expansion-increases-us-team-by-5-new-members|news/announce-a-new-director-of-sales-supply-chain-marketing|news/named-to-south-florida-business-journal-2017-top-private-company-list|news/announce-a-new-director-of-sales-enablement|news/to-exhibit-at-nacds-2017-in-san-diego-ca|news/to-exhibit-at-iltacon-2017-in-las-vegas-nv|news/to-exhibit-at-inman-connect-2017-in-san-francisco-ca|news/to-exhibit-at-infoag-2017-in-st-louis-mo|news/to-exhibit-at-avma-2017-in-indianapolis-in|news/to-exhibit-at-mwaa-2017-in-chicago-il|news/to-exhibit-at-wtc-2017-in-las-vegas-nv|news/to-exhibit-at-invest-2017-in-new-york-city-ny|news/to-exhibit-at-igss-2017-in-amsterdam-netherlands|news/to-exhibit-at-hitec-2017-in-toronto-canada|news/to-exhibit-at-infocomm-2017-in-orlando-fl|news/to-exhibit-at-unite-europe-2017-in-amsterdam-netherlands|news/to-exhibit-at-sabre-travel-technology-exchange-2017-in-las-vega-nv|news/to-exhibit-at-ncsc-2017-in-washington-dc|news/to-recieve-healthiest-employer-award|news/to-exhibit-at-naa-2017-in-atlanta-ga|news/to-exhibit-at-ala-2017-in-chicago-il|news/to-exhibit-at-iste-2017-in-san-antonio-tx|news/to-exhibit-at-hci-2017-in-boston-ma|news/to-exhibit-at-money2020-in-copenhagen-denmark|news/to-exhibit-at-irce-2017-in-chicago-il|news/to-exhibit-at-safety-2017-in-denver-co|news/to-exhibit-at-e3-2017-in-los-angeles-ca|news/to-exhibit-at-cfma-conference-in-phoenix-az)(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}{R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
```